# how to remove a comma from a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm having difficulty trying to remove the commas in my list. I have tried using split(',') but then realised you can't because its all numbers. Any advice would be great !

```
class UnorderedList:

def __init__(self):
    self.head = None


def add(self, item): #add to the beginning of the list
    new_node = Node(item)
    new_node.set_next(self.head)
    self.head = new_node

def size(self):
    current = self.head
    count = 0
    while current != None:
        count = count + 1
        current = current.get_next()
    return count

def is_empty(self):
    return self.head == None

def search(self,item):
    current = self.head
    while current != None:
        if current.get_data() == item:
            return True
        else:
            current = current.get_next()
    return False

def remove(self, item):
    #Assumes the item is in the linked list
    current = self.head
    previous = None
    found = False
    while not found:
        if current.get_data() == item:
            found = True
        else:
            previous = current
            current = current.get_next()
    if previous == None:
        self.head = current.get_next() #remove the first node
    else:
        previous.set_next(current.get_next())

def __str__(self):
    my_list1 = []
    current = self.head
    while current != None:
        my_list1 += [current.get_data()]
        current = current.get_next()
    return str(my_list1)

def __iter__(self):
    return LinkedListIterator(self.head)
```

My answer is coming out as [8, 7, 6, 3, 5]
But I want it is [8 7 6 3 5]

Comment: What you want is invalid. [1 2 3] is invalid syntax in Python

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Also you can use: `str(my_list1).replace( ','  , ' ' )`

Comment: This is the better answer. I always forget about the .replace method :D

Answer (score 2):

Instead of:

`str(my_list1)`

Do:

`"[{0}]".format(" " .join(str(x) for x in my_list1))`

Comment: get an error >>> TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type NoneType)

Answer (score 0):

[1 2 3] is invalid. You can try something like this instead:

```
' '.join(map(str, your_list))  # => '1 2 3'
```